# I consistently get an error with respect to the final output

Tags: java

I consistently get different output than I expected. However, the code very apparently is running correctly, providing the desired output elements, with some additional redundant elements like an appetizer and main course.

Please, see the attached code, and output when run on the Eclipse IDE.

```
//class FoodOrder
class Main {
// Method to display menu
static void display(String menu[]) {
for (int i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
System.out.println("  " + i + " - " + menu[i]);
}
System.out.print("Enter the number for your selection: ");
}

// main method
public static void main(String[] args) {
// menu lists:
String mainMenu[] = { "Nothing", "Appetizer", "Main Course", "Dessert" };
String dessertMenu[] = { "Nothing", "Baklava", "Rice Pudding", "Chocolate Cake" };
String appetizerMenu[] = { "Nothing", "Oysters", "Grilled Octopus", "Hummus" };
String mainCourseMenu[] = { "Nothing", "Steak", "Chicken", "Fish", "Vegetarian" };
String toppingsMenu[] = { "Nothing", "Olive Oil", "Paprika", "Olives" };

String list = "";

// create an instance of Scanner class
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

boolean valid;

System.out.println("Welcome to the food festival!");

String ans;

do {

System.out.print("Would you like to place an order? ");
ans = sc.next();

valid = ((ans.equals("YES")) || ans.equals("YEs") || ans.equals("Yes") || ans.equals("yES")
|| ans.equals("yeS") || ans.equals("yEs") || ans.equals("YeS") || ans.equals("yes")
|| (ans.equals("NO")) || ans.equals("No") || ans.equals("nO") || ans.equals("no"));

} while (!valid);

if ((ans.equals("NO")) || (ans.equals("No")) || (ans.equals("nO")) || (ans.equals("no"))) {

System.out.println("Thank you for stopping by, maybe next time you’ll sample our menu.");
return;
}

if (ans.equals("YES") || ans.equals("YEs") || ans.equals("Yes") || ans.equals("yES") || ans.equals("yeS")
|| ans.equals("yEs") || ans.equals("YeS") || ans.equals("yes")) {

System.out.print("What is your name for the order? ");
String name = sc.next();

System.out.println("");

int m, n, k;

while (true) {

Menu:

// proocess to select the menu items
System.out.println("Select from menu, " + name);

display(mainMenu);

n = sc.nextInt();
if (n == 0)
break;

if (n == 1) {
while (true) {
System.out.println("");
System.out.println("Appetizer Menu:");
display(appetizerMenu);

m = sc.nextInt();
list = list + "Appetizer:[" + appetizerMenu[m] + ": ";

if (m == 0) {
break;
}

while (true) {

System.out.println("");
System.out.println("Toppings Menu:");
display(toppingsMenu);
k = sc.nextInt();
if (k == 0)
break;
list = list + toppingsMenu[k] + " ";
}

list = list + "]\n";

}

}

if (n == 2) {

while (true) {
System.out.println("");
System.out.println("Main Course Menu:");
display(mainCourseMenu);

m = sc.nextInt();
list = list + "Main Course :[" + mainCourseMenu[m] + ": ";

if (m == 0) {
break;
}

while (true) {

System.out.println("");
System.out.println("Toppings Menu:");
display(toppingsMenu);
k = sc.nextInt();
if (k == 0)
break;
list = list + toppingsMenu[k] + "]\n";
}

}

}

if (n == 3) {

while (true) {
System.out.println("");
System.out.println("Dessert Menu:");
display(dessertMenu);

m = sc.nextInt();
list = list + "Main Course :[" + dessertMenu[m] + ": ";

if (m == 0) {
break;
}

while (true) {

System.out.println("");
System.out.println("Toppings Menu:");
display(toppingsMenu);
k = sc.nextInt();
if (k == 0)
break;
list = list + toppingsMenu[k] + "]\n";
}

}

}

} // end while loop

System.out.println("Here is your order " + name);
System.out.println(list);
System.out.println("Enjoy your meal!");

} // end of if
}// main method
}// end of class
```

This is the output I am supposed to get:

```
Here is your order Superman:
Appetizer: [ Hummus: Olives, Olive Oil ]
Main Course: [ Fish: Paprika ]
Dessert: [ Baklava: ]
Enjoy your meal!
```

Unfortunately, I am getting this output:

```
Here is your order Superman:
Appetizer:[Hummus: Olives Olive Oil ]
Appetizer:[Nothing: Main Course :[Fish: Paprika]
Main Course :[Nothing: Main Course :[Baklava:
Main Course :[Nothing:
Enjoy your meal!
```

Comment: Please correct the indentation.

Comment: Stackoverflow should have a feature to auto format code ..

Comment: Seems like your question is missing the top part of your code.  The first line is a syntax error, and your bracing doesn't match up, per the extra closing braces at the bottom. - please supply code that compiles and runs.

Answer (score 0):

I did some assumptions, and made the implementation.
There are some errors with your implementation:

1. You need to check if the list is empty or not to add ","
2. You are first adding the selection before checking if it was exit option

I think this could be the code that you are looking for:

```
public static String collectToppings(Scanner sc, String[] toppingsMenu) {
    String list = "";
    while (true) {

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Toppings Menu:");
        display(toppingsMenu);
        int k = sc.nextInt();
        if (k == 0)
            break;

        if (list.length() == 0) {
            list = toppingsMenu[k];
        } else {
            list += ", " + toppingsMenu[k];
        }
    }
    if (list.length() > 0) {
        return list + " ]\r\n\r\n";
    } else {
        return "]\r\n\r\n";
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = "Superman";
    int m, n;
    String[] mainMenu = new String[] { "Exit", "Appetizer Menu", "Toppings Menu", "Main Course Menu" };

    String[] appetizerMenu = new String[] {"Exit", "Hummus"};
    String[] mainCourseMenu = new String[] {"Exit", "Fish"};
    String[] dessertMenu = new String[] {"Exit", "Baklava"};
    String list ="";

    while (true) {

        // proocess to select the menu items
        System.out.println("Select from menu, " + name);

        display(mainMenu);

        n = sc.nextInt();
        if (n == 0)
            break;

        if (n == 1) {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Appetizer Menu:");
                display(appetizerMenu);

                m = sc.nextInt();
                if (m == 0) {
                    break;
                }

                list = list + "Appetizer: [ "  + appetizerMenu[m] + ": ";
                String[] toppingsMenu = new String[] {"Exit", "Olives", "Olive Oil"};
                list += collectToppings(sc, toppingsMenu);
            }

        }

        if (n == 2) {

            while (true) {
                display(mainCourseMenu);

                m = sc.nextInt();
                if (m == 0) {
                    break;
                }

                list = list + "Main Course: [ " + mainCourseMenu[m] + ": ";
                String[] toppingsMenu = new String[] {"Exit", "Paprika"};
                list += collectToppings(sc, toppingsMenu) ;
            }

        }

        if (n == 3) {

            while (true) {
                display(dessertMenu);

                m = sc.nextInt();
                if (m == 0) {
                    break;
                }

                list = list + "Dessert: [ " + dessertMenu[m] + ": ";
                String[] toppingsMenu = new String[] {"Exit", "...", "..."};
                list += collectToppings(sc, toppingsMenu);
            }

        }

    }

    System.out.println("Here is your order " + name + ":\r\n");
    System.out.println(list);
    System.out.println("Enjoy your meal!");

}

private static void display(String[] menu) {
    int i = 0;
    for (String s : menu) {
        System.out.println(i++ + ". " + s);
    }
}
```